# Password Box Text

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, textbox, login-control

I currently have a login box for my website.  I want to add text into the password box to tell the user which password of theirs to use.  ie.  the password box would contain the words (Please use windows log on Password) and when they click on it, the wording will disappear and allow them to type in their password.
I could do this with the login box using something like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="UserName" class="txtbox" runat="server" text="NUID" Width="240px"
 onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue) {this.value='';$(this).css('color','black');}"  
 onblur="if(this.value=='') {this.value=this.defaultValue;$(this).css('color','rgb(173,180,195)');}"></asp:TextBox>
```

However, with the password it does not seem to work.  This seems to be due to the fact that is has the textmode="password" parameter.

Does anyone know how to do this with the ASP.NET Textbox in password mode.  Not a HTML textobx.

Here is my current code.

HTML

```
<asp:Login ID="Login1" class="loginbox" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" 
      DisplayRememberMe="False" UserNameLabelText="NUID:" 
      FailureText="Incorrect login. Please try again."  TitleText="" DestinationPageUrl="default.aspx" onauthenticate="Login1_Authenticate">
      <TextBoxStyle Width="110px" />
      <LoginButtonStyle Font-Names="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" Height="24px" />
                                        <LayoutTemplate>
                                            <table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" 
                                                style="border-collapse:collapse; height:113px">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0"> 
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td valign="baseline">
                                                                <div class="textlogin">NUID</div>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>                                                               
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td>
                                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" class="textloginbox" runat="server"  Font-Bold="true"></asp:TextBox>
                                                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" 
                                                                        ControlToValidate="UserName" ErrorMessage="User Name is required." 
                                                                        ToolTip="User Name is required." ValidationGroup="Login1" ForeColor="#FF0000" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="14px">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr><td style="height:3px;"></td></tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td>
                                                                <div class="textlogin">Password</div>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>  
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td>

                                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" class="textloginbox" TextMode="Password" Font-Bold="true"></asp:TextBox>
                                                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server" 
                                                                        ControlToValidate="Password" ErrorMessage="Password is required." 
                                                                        ToolTip="Password is required." ValidationGroup="Login1" ForeColor="#FF0000" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="14px">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td align="center" style="color:#DA6426;">
                                                                    <asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td align="right">
                                                                <asp:ImageButton ID="LoginButton" runat="server" CssClass="loginbutton" CommandName="Login" ValidationGroup="Login1"  ImageUrl="~/Icons/Enter Arrow 30.png" />
                                                                &nbsp;&nbsp;       
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </LayoutTemplate>
                                    <TitleTextStyle BackColor="#FFFFE0" Font-Bold="True" 
                                        ForeColor="#FFFFFF" Height="0px"/>
                                    </asp:Login>
```

Comment: `TextMode="Password"` would render as an password input. You don't expect a user to read what you set in `********`, do you?

Comment: Yeah.  That is why I wanted to know if there was a way to do it with textmode="password".  Maybe have jquery change it or something.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the placeholder attribute? So after ID="Password", put in placeholder="Enter Test Here". It won't work for IE8 and down though... try this (using jQuery)

```
$("#Password").focus(function()
{
    if($(this).val() == "Your Text Here")
    {
        $(this).val("");
    }
});

$("#Password").blur(function()
{
    if($(this).val() == "")
    {
        $(this).val("Your Text Here");
    }
});
```

Edit: After reading through the comment above, he has a point. Using this code will render "Your Text Here" unreadable. However, the placeholder attribute will display properly, even if it's not for IE 8 and below

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  We are required to develop for ie7 and up.  Horrible rule.  Yes.  I understand the thing about textmode="Password".  Just wanted to know if there was a way around it.